# What is causing a white stripe on top of some slides taken with my film camera?

Tags: film, troubleshooting, slides, canon-1v

I am using slide film in a Canon EOS 1V and I recently discovered that **some** of my pictures turn out to have a **white stripe on top of the frame**, e.g. in these ones:

[image]
[image]   [image]

What I find weird is that only some pictures do have that stripe, while others turn out perfectly fine.

---

- I thought it could be the **sealing**, but taken that it occurs so
  unregularly I don't think this is the issue.
- I also don't think it is the **shutter**, because if it was, wouldn't
  the white stripe be more parallel to the border?
- It's also not some stain or anything from the devloping process - it
  can't be rubbed off etc.
- The stripe shows on the slides as well, so it's not due to the scanning either.

**What could be the reason and what can I do to solve it?**

Comment: Are your slides "loose" or mounted in slide holders?

Comment: @MichaelClark they’re loose, not mounted... does that make any difference?

Comment: Well, if they are mounted some of the slides could be slightly tilted in the holders, and the line may be present in all of them but only visible in some of them, with the edge on that side covered up by the holder in the others.

Comment: How long are the exposures for the affected images?

Answer (score 2):

> I also don't think it is the shutter, because if it was, wouldn't the white stripe be more parallel to the border?

Shutter issues don't always manifest themselves with light bands exactly parallel to the edge of the frame. If the second curtain is sticking slightly on one side of the bottom of the film plane (top of the inverted image) before closing, it could be at a slight angle before it finally closes.

That's what this looks like to me.

If the affected images are fairly long exposures, it's also possible that you have light leaking through the viewfinder and around the edge of the mirror which *should* be totally cover the focusing screen in the top of the light box. But that doesn't usually result in such a specific effect on the very edge of the frame. It's usually more of an overall fogging of the entire frame or more complex patterns caused by the leaking light bouncing around the various edges inside the camera's light box and off the back of the glass in the lens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That would explain why the issue only occurs on some images depending on the shutter speed. Stupid question, but do you maybe know whether the stripe will always stay on top of the picture if it actually is a shutter problem or is it possible that it might go right through the middle?

Comment: Problems with a shutter curtain not closing properly will always extend to the edge of the frame. If there are gaps between the "leaves" of a shutter curtain it can show up in the middle of the frame. In an extreme case, an [entire leaf can be missing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/86758/15871).