# DSLR lifespan vs shutter count when shutter is replaced

Tags: dslr, shutter-actuations

I know the lifespan of DSLR largely depends on the shutter count. But I want to know how does the lifespan of DSLR is affected when the shutter is replaced. If we install fresh new shutter in a used DLSR does this mean we can expect double life under normal using conditions, given that there is no other failures in the system.

Does the sensor life depends on shutter count? or can we expect to use camera according to new shutter life?

Comment: Finding a second-hand camera with a low shutter count is possibly going to be less expensive than having the shutter replaced.

Comment: @xenoid well I found deals where a DSLR with lower shutter count is lot more expensive. Like a Nikon D750 with higher shutter count is for $500 but  with a lower shutter count is more than $1100. I checked the cost of replacing a new shutter is $300 - $400 approx.

Comment: What is the shutter count of the less expensive unit and how much do you expect to use it?

Comment: @LightBender one of them has shutter count of 145,000 for $500. That I planning to have shutter replaced by Nikon if I see any issues with it. But the one with low shutter count of 55,000 is for $1500. I intent to use it for 1-2 year for occasional photography for trips. And if plan to buy newer/better full frame later.

Comment: I can't directly advise you on this because you are essentially taking a gamble here. I can only help articulate the risk. There is no guarantee that the shutter will fail at 150k, I've owned workhorse cameras I've gone nearly double the shutter life on, and had some fail 10% past the mark. So ultimately, it's up to you if you feel the risk is worth the reward. Don't just consider the money though, will your current equipment hold you until you are ready to replace? What does it cost you (personally) if the equipment fails in the field? All things to consider.

Comment: @LightBender my main doubt is that - is shutter that important that if it fails the whole camera is waste? That is my main question, if we get the shutter replaced with a new one by the manufacturer does it still mean that Camera is not worth taking risk? Because cost of replacing the shutter is way lower than paying for a used camera with less shutter count.

Answer (score 1):

The shutter mechanism is one of the few mechanical components on a DSLR(other than hinges, seals, buttons, dials). The Shutter mechanism is the second most complicated part of a DSLR after the sensor. If replaced properly, by the authorised service centre, It will almost breathe new life into your DSLR. Do not worry about the technological obsolescence of your DSLR.

Based on your name, I am assuming you are from India. So, in India, finding a good used DSLR(better model than the one you have) with low shutter count is going to be far more expensive than just replacing the shutter mechanism. As long as the main and command dials and D-Pad are working fine, replacing your shutter is going to **almost** renew the life of your camera. **The sensor does not wear out**(unless you are doing astro-photography and star trails, in which case hotspots and burnt pixels become far more common and you can consider the sensor to be wearing out).

Look at pro tog cheap camera challenge by DRTV. You don't need the latest and greatest DSLR for great pics but your DSLR *definitely* needs a shutter to be able to take pics.

So, I would say If your DSLR shutter life has reached the rated life, GET IT REPLACED IMMEDIATELY. There is no need to go out and buy a new camera but get it replaced ASAP. a torn shutter/broken mechanism can damage the sensor which will be a real nightmare(DSLR is rendered useless, resale value will crash making it even more difficult for you to upgrade if you want to/need to).

*YOU CAN EXPECT TO USE THE CAMERA **CLOSE** TO THE NEW SHUTTER's LIFE*(depends on the condition of the dials and buttons).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am not in india.  I am just a hobbyist and blog my photos. I am talking about Nikon D750 with slightly higher shutter count but in good condition for $500. I know after sometime if shutter fails I can replace it for approx $300-$400. I do want to spend significant amount to buy latest camera just to make it perfect. For a lesser shutter count I can get same camera for $1100 - $1400.

Comment: I would never replace a shutter assembly simply because it had reached its rated number of actuations. It's very rare for a shutter to suffer catastrophic failure without giving smaller warning signs first. Some of those would include a slow second curtain (so that the top of the frame/bottom of the sensor is progressively exposed brighter near the top edge), a "sticky" shutter curtain that never completely closes, or maybe even [this obvious gap](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/86758/15871) where one of the blades in the curtain is gone.

Comment: @Rajendra V  I would say the Nikon D750 is a pretty good camera and can hold it's own even in today's landscape. Unless you are looking for video capabilities, in which case I'd say go for Nikon Z. IMHO, You can later spend the $300-$600 you save on something more useful. Like lenses or an upgraded tripod or camera bag or GND filter set or macro extension tube set or bellows or Speedlight system. **Or even a second body as backup**. You could also buy a dehumidifying cabinet if you live near the coast.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing a *failing* shutter will usually lengthen the useful life of a camera.

But the useful life of most DSLR's is less defined by mechanical failure and more by technical obsolescence. Most DSLR's are replaced by something better because digital technology improves every few years. Also because most cameras are sold at the lower tiers there are potential upgrades from day one.

The cameras that don't get upgraded tend to be those owned by people who take fewer pictures and never approach the limits of their shutter's mechanical durability.

Personally, I would assume a used camera with a shutter count that *significantly* exceeds the rated life of the shutter is for sale because the shutter is failing. For a high shutter count camera below rating, I wouldn't worry much. For one just over the rated life, I would assume that someone is upgrading and using shutter count as a rationale.

Comment: I'd argue against the fact that the *useful* life of a DSLR or any digital camera depends on technical obsolescence. Although cameras are still improving, any modern high end camera will produce great results. A camera does not become useless when the next model is released. When the shutter fails, however, it becomes significantly harder to take photos.

Comment: @timvrhn I don’t disagree Older cameras are perfectly capable of great pictures. But shopping is easier than making great pictures and new gear is a way of convincing people (including yourself) that one’s a serious photographer. But besides that new DSLR’s are better…the Nikon F5 film camera is still about as good as it gets. It’s digital stablemate, the D1 is as obsolescent as an iMac G3. To put it another way, there are good reasons to buy or use an older DSLR. But there are good reasons to replace an old but full operational DSLR with a later model and most people do that.

Comment: Cameras are used for more than making pictures. For example they are, as these comments prove, useful for arguments on the internet.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens " _But shopping is easier than making great pictures and new gear is a way of convincing people (including yourself) that one’s a serious photographer_ " I think you are ignoring the price aspect. People's budgets are very different from each other. With your budget capability, it might be worth it to discard older cameras when better cameras come on to the market. But there are many people, for whom technical obsolescence is acceptable . They want to keep using their older cameras for long, even if better cameras come into the market, rather than spending on new one.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens I am just a hobbyist and blog my photos. I am talking about Nikon D750 with slightly higher shutter count but in good condition for $500. I know after sometime if shutter fails I can replace it for approx $300-$400.  I do want to spend significant amount to buy latest camera just to make it perfect. For a lesser shutter count I can get same camera for $1100 - $1400.

Comment: @silverrahul I don’t disagree. There are many different kinds of people with their own values and opinions. I mean using a tripod is probably the best way to improve pictures. But image stabilization is nothing to sneeze on. That cameras become obsolete is just a fact. It is not my opinion about the values you. me,  or anyone else should or shouldn’t have. The question is rooted in economics. Obsolescence is a consideration in regards to the marketplace. It can be used to advantage or not.

Comment: @RajendraV The google says the d750 is rated at 150k actuations. That’s significant use…100 pictures a day every day for four years or 300 pictures a week for ten years. I

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens that is what is my main concern. we always only talks about shutter count which is a mechanical part. so if the camera is in good condition and get a new shutter installed. does it affect the reliability of camera. Given it has mostly all the functionalities that are in modern camera that most of us are going to use.

Comment: @RajendraV For me, I would buy one with a warranty for that kind of money. There are lots of camera shops that sell used gear with them. They know what is junk. They try to avoid reselling it. It is not worth them doing and if they make a mistake they fix it. They know what to look for when buying for resale and don’t pay too much.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens The camera obsolescence is indeed a fact . But, the trade off between living with obsolete camera or spending more on a new camera depends on each individuals budget , usage and priorities. It is too much of a generalisation to say that it is better to buy new camera rather than installing new shutter system.

Comment: @silverrahul That is why I did not say what you seem to think I said.